How to ensure I'm using the new version of Ruby I downloaded instead of the system version on Mac?
I'm following this tutorial on learning Ruby, and have followed the instructions on installing the latest version of Ruby (3.2.4).
However I'm not sure how to switch to 3.2.4 on my Mac so I'm using this version. I have updated the PATH to include this version:
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@3.2/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/USERNAME/.zshrc

however when I do which ruby it points to the old version path: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby
Any idea how to ensure I'm using version 3.2.4 ?
I have read that the best way to do this is to add the version to Ruby Version Manager (rvm) and then control which version to use from there, however I'm not sure how to do that.
EDIT:
Here is my environment:
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.1 (2020-03-31 patchlevel 83) [x86_64-darwin19]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.1_2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-19
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5
     - /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global/bin
     - /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@3.2/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@3.2/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby@3.2/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
     - /Users/user/Documents/flutter/bin
     - /Users/user/.rvm/bin


Does this answer your question? Installing Ruby gems not working with Homebrew

Personally, I am using the following export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0:$PATH. The first is for ruby itself and the second is for gem dir

No @ClarencetheBard that's about Ruby gems, my question is about Ruby itself

Shouldn't the most popular answer fix your issue? export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH The question is about ruby gem, but ruby needs to work first in order for ruby gem to work after all.

I executed that export command and now when I do ruby -v it says 2.7.1, still not 3.2.4 @ClarencetheBard

Just tested and it does work for me. Been a while since I fixed this issue so I am not sure as to why it doesn't work for you.

Not sure. I have added my environment to my initial post to give a snapshot @ClarencetheBard


I have read that the best way to do this is to add the version to Ruby Version Manager (rvm)

RVM was at one point in time the defacto solution but there are a lot of very good alternatives today such as RBenv and ASDF.

However I'm not sure how to switch to 3.2.4 on my Mac so I'm using this version.

With RVM you switch shell versions with the rvm use command followed by the version:
rvm use 3.2.4

That places that version of Ruby and its binaries (ruby, irb, etc) onto your path as well as it's gems and their binaries.
The --default option can be used to make this the default Ruby version for new shell windows.
See The Basics of RVM.
